# I want to add google captcha V2 before placing an order in Magento 2.3.x

Tags: magento2.3, captcha, google

Magento 2.3.X - How to add the google captcha V2 on the checkout page before place the order button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all add your captcha element in any html template as per your need.

`<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="YOUR_GOOGLE_CAPTCHA_KEY" id="html_element"></div>`

Now add below code in your any .phtml template file which one must load on checkout page

> I used
> **/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/onepage.phtml**

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=waitForElement&render=explicit' async defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function waitForElement(query){
    var poops = setInterval(function(){
        if(document.querySelector('.g-recaptcha')){            
            clearInterval(poops);
            window.checkout_captcha = grecaptcha.render("html_element", {
            sitekey: '--GzJK',
            callback: function() {
                console.log('recaptcha callback');
            }
        });
        }
    }, 100);
}
</script>
```

Now we need to prevent to place order without select google captcha so we need JS validation.

> you can write as per your need at place order function
> **/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/proceed-to-checkout.js**

```
if(jQuery('.g-recaptcha').html() !=''){                                    
    var response = grecaptcha.getResponse(window.checkout_captcha);
    if(response.length==0){   
        //your condition
       errorMessage = $.mage.__('Please verify that you are not a robot');
        alert({ content: errorMessage });
        return;
    }
}
```

**If work for you then please mark as a solution.**

Note: don't add any code directly in vendor. override file in your theme/module